# How to get input in the middle of a printed line in .NET 3 console applcation

Tags: c#, .net, input

My question is rather simple, but I can't seem to find a simple answer, no answer at all for that point.

What I want to do is to print a question and then have an answer field, and then write more text after that without waiting for input:

```
This is a program that solves second degree equations using this formula ax*x + bx + c = d
write your numbers! {WHERE I WANT TO WRITE AND GET INPUT}x*x + bx+ c = d
```

I wrote `{WHERE I WANT TO WRITE AND GET INPUT}` where I would want to write when the application is running, the after that get the input, so the application can start doing the math!

Comment: Is this for a console project?

Comment: Use `Console.SetCursorPosition`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setcursorposition

Comment: Thanks @Dai this is exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: Oh, I might think about using that, a quick question @Dai how do I make it insert instead of overwrite when I use this?

Comment: `My question is rather simple` definitely *not*. Creating a console GUI is hard, because there's simply no support for this, because it's 1990s technology. Before the new Windows Terminal in Windows 10, there was very limited support for console positioning and formatting. With Windows Terminal, you can finally use the same terminal capabilities found on Linux

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `ncurses` disagrees :) As does legions of insurance-company employees who prefer mainframe-style UIs: just tab through fields without faffing around with mouse cursors and whatnot ;)

Comment: @AUniquee if you want to create a good-looking UI, you can use eg Miguel de Icaza's [gui.cs](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/gui.cs) library, that allows you to create the same kind of applications built in the 1990s. It's *easier* to create a fancy dialog box or text field with `gui.cs` than writing the positioning and reading the console input

Comment: @Dai ncurses existed in 1990 as well. I remember trying to use it on an AIX workstation us students weren't supposed to use. Along with far better console UI libraries like TurboVision. That worked on my DOS box. I dare say though, that highly paid IBM consultants still use console-style knowledge-base applications, and charge you for it. Who's going to steal the KB if few even remember what dBase IV or Clipper was?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ahhh, dBase - aka CSV-gone-wild ;) Let me tell you about Progress "Open"Edge sometime...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTE: In the context of console programs, the term "cursor" refers to the caret, or insertion point, of console text - it does *not* refer to your mouse-pointer.

---

You can use `Console.SetCursorPosition` to control where text is written to the console, but it comes with numerous caveats:

Namely, you will *need* to get the current cursor position with `Console.CursorTop` and `Console.CursorLeft` (or `Console.GetCursorPosition` on .NET 5). <sub>This is so that you can know where the cursor is when you print a field - because the console buffer (which can be sized differently to the window) can be resized by the user at any point - this is also why many console programs output garbled text when resized if they aren't controlling the cursor position properly.</sub>

Here's an example implementation of your problem: placeholders in a mathematical expression. Note that only single-characters can be inserted at each placeholder (represented by an underscore character). If you want to make the placeholder *dynamically expandable* as more digits are entered then that's an exercise for the reader (hint: re-print the line by using `\r`).

```
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            const String line1 = "This is a program that solves second degree equations using this formula ax*x + bx + c = d";
            const String line2 = "write your numbers! _x*x + _x+ _c = d";

            // HACK:
            if( Console.BufferWidth < line2.Length )
            {
                Console.WriteLine( "Please resize your console window to {0} columns and restart this program.", line2.Length );
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine( line1 );
            Console.WriteLine( line2 );

            // Get the character indexes of the placeholders:
            Int32 pos1 = line2.IndexOf( '_' );
            Int32 pos2 = line2.IndexOf( '_', pos1 + 1 );
            Int32 pos3 = line2.IndexOf( '_', pos2 + 1 );
            Int32 pos4 = line2.IndexOf( 'd', pos3 + 1 );

#if NET5_0
            (Int32 x, Int32 y) = Console.GetCursorPosition();
#else
            Int32 x = Console.CursorLeft;
            Int32 y = Console.CursorTop;
#endif

            // Curiously, `y` is 2 for the second line (implying base 1), but SetCursorPosition uses base 0, so adjust it:
            y = y - 1;

            // Assuming the placeholders are on the same line without any wrapping:
            Console.SetCursorPosition( left: pos1, top: y );

            Int32? a = ReadDigit();
            if( a == null ) return;

            Console.SetCursorPosition( left: pos2, top: y );

            Int32? b = ReadDigit();
            if( b == null ) return;

            Console.SetCursorPosition( left: pos3, top: y );

            Int32? c = ReadDigit();
            if( c == null ) return;

            // Compute 'd':
            Double d = 1234;// SolveQuadradicFormula( a, b, c );

            // Move cursor where the 'd' is:
            Console.SetCursorPosition( left: pos4, top: y );

            // Then write the value of d:
            Console.Write( d );
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        private static Int32? ReadDigit()
        {
            do
            {
                ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey();
                if( Char.IsDigit( key.KeyChar ) )
                {
                    return key.KeyChar - '0';
                }
                else if( key.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape )
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            while( true );
        }
```

Screenshot proof:

Waiting for user-input:

[image]

After pressing `1` on my keyboard:

[image]

Then, after pressing `2` on my keyboard:

[image]

Then, after pressing `3` on my keyboard (which also shows the value for `d`, which is just `1234`: a fake placeholder value for now):

[image]

Comment: This is a great aswer but I have a small question, how would I make this so i can write bigger numbers? Without insert maybe?

Comment: @AUniquee You will need to re-print the rest of the line after each placeholder.